# How to find the IP of your turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the turtlebot network setup it says to bing your turtlebot using its IP the tutorial also says the IP was figured out in the last step I don't know what my turtlebot IP is please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57573/how-to-find-the-ip-of-your-turtlebot/) by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Determine the IP address following step 2 in http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on 2013-03-09**:
I've done step 2 I just don't know which is the IP for the Turtlebot i'm brand new to robotics and have  no idea what i am doing

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-09**:
Use the command ifconfig

**Comment by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on 2013-03-09**:
Which one is the turtlebot three titles pop up  eth0 eth1 lo should it be under one of those

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-09**:
Are you using a wireless connection?

**Comment by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on 2013-03-09**:
Yes I am using a wireless connection and I am working on a 2008 mac book pro running unbuntu 12.10

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-09**:
I believe the wireless is suppose to be wlan0.  Are you able to connect to the wireless now?

**Comment by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on 2013-03-09**:
My computer says I'm connected though a wireless network I reconnected to it and I got the same thing  and no wlan0

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-09**:
Please edit you post with the output of `ifconfig`. If only one has an inetaddr that one is probably your IP.

**Comment by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on 2013-03-09**:
Both eth1 and lo have inetaddr would lo be the robot the computer says it's a local loop back link

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-09**:
No, lo is *local*, i.e. no outside connection. It's probably eth1 then.

**Comment by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on 2013-03-09**:
The local connection would make since because the turtlebot is plugged into this computer

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-09**:
Wait, you're doing everything from one machine? Then you probably don't need to do anything and it will just work. If you are doing networking, the `lo` interface is NOT the place to look for the IP as it is local.

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-10**:
Hey, try these commands in your terminal...sudo service network-manager restart. And then type ifconfig to check wlan0 is reflected ? Post output of everything here please ??

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-10**:
Hey, try these commands in your terminal...

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-11**:
Given the sparse information, I think eth1 is his wireless. `iwconfig` should clear that up.